# How do I load SQLX records to Vec of structs in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a table named instruments with the  following fields:

- `id`,
- `instrument_token` (integer)
- `tradingsymbol` (nullable string field)

I have defined a Rust struct as below

```
pub struct Instrument {
    pub id: i64,
    pub instrument_token: i32,
    pub tradingsymbol: Option<String>,
}
```

I query and create a `Vec<Instrument>` inside a function as follows using SQLX

```rust
     let records = sqlx::query!(r"select * from instruments").fetch_all(&app_context.db_connection).await?;


        let mut all_instruments: Vec<Instrument> = Vec::new();
        for rec in records {
            all_instruments.push(Instrument {
                id: rec.id,
                instrument_token: rec.instrument_token,
                tradingsymbol: rec.tradingsymbol,
            });
        }
```

Here `&app_context.db_connection` is `&pool` instance.

Is this there a better way to load records to a struct using SQLX.
If yes how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your record and data type have the same field names and types, you can use [`query_as!`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.3.4/sqlx/struct.QueryAs.html#method.fetch_all) instead:

```
let records: Vec<Instrument> =
    sqlx::query_as!(Instrument, r"select * from instruments")
        .fetch_all(&app_context.db_connection)
        .await?;
```

Comment: Should all the fields in the struct and DB exactly match, or can I be picky about whatever fields I want to use?

Comment: @AsnimPAnsari I believe all columns in your query must match the fields of the type. You can write your query to only select certain columns, though.